# Screen goes black for a while

Tags: intel-graphics, hp

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS  on my HP 820 G1 i5 4310u 2.0 Ghz.

- Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4310U CPU @ 2.00GHz
- Intel HD Graphics 4400 (Intel Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller)
- OS type: 64-bit

The screen often goes black and sometimes stays like this.

I've come up with the *temporary* solution of using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> later <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f7</kbd>

Comment: Do you know any better solution? Thank you

Comment: same issue here HP 840 G1 i5

Answer (score 0):

Si. Me fallaba el sensor de cierre de la tapa de la pantalla .
 Deshabilite en  el OS que se suspendiera si se cerraba la tapa y ya no tengo problema .

Comment: I was missing the closing sensor on the cover of the screen. I disabled the OS to be suspended if the cover was closed and I no longer have a problem.